# Understanding TFLearn IMDB sentiment analysis

Tags: neural-networks, python, tensorflow

I am very new to machine learning and deep learning. I recently studied RNN and LSTM networks. One application I came across was sentiment analysis on imdb movie reviews using TFLearn and TensorFlow.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical, pad_sequences
from tflearn.datasets import imdb

# IMDB Dataset loading
train, test, _ = imdb.load_data(path='imdb.pkl', n_words=10000,
                                valid_portion=0.1)
trainX, trainY = train
testX, testY = test

# Data preprocessing
# Sequence padding
trainX = pad_sequences(trainX, maxlen=100, value=0.)
testX = pad_sequences(testX, maxlen=100, value=0.)
# Converting labels to binary vectors
trainY = to_categorical(trainY, nb_classes=2)
testY = to_categorical(testY, nb_classes=2)

# Network building
net = tflearn.input_data([None, 100])
net = tflearn.embedding(net, input_dim=10000, output_dim=128)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128, dropout=0.8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.001,
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_set=(testX, testY), show_metric=True,
          batch_size=32)
```

I have few questions regarding this code.

1. How does our model know which words to use for train and which ones
   to use for test. Since there aren't any predefined bag of words
2. How does this model knows about sentiment of non-english words.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You use a predefined dataset and training and test are both seperated from each other, when you use this line:

```
train, test, _ = imdb.load_data(path='imdb.pkl', n_words=10000,
                            valid_portion=0.1)
```

It will load training and test set from sample.

2) it doesn't matter for model which language sentiment are, it will create a model without knowing which word is English and which is not.The number of occurrence and other features are important not word itself.

Comment: I get your first point. But for second as you said "No of occurrences is important " what does that mean. I mean let's say a word "great" is written in sentence for 10 times and word "bad" is written in word for5 times. How does our model know "great" is positive and therefore give overall response as positive? **IS THE WORD'S POSITIVITY /NEGATIVITY PREDEFINED IN TFLEARN?**

Comment: @no , it's not defined which word is positive or negative, I can't really explain how it does that , I suggest you read more about Deep Learning methods to understand how they extract features from data.

Comment: any link would be really helpful